# Matching by part url

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two indices - one contains "document" objects with `_id=<url of the document>`, e.g. `http://site/folder/document_name.doc` ; the other contains "folder" objects with `_id=<url of the folder>`, e.g. `http://site/folder`

In my node.js script I need to match documents to folders, i.e. I search for all folder urls, and then for each of them I search for all documents which urls start with the folder url

I can't seem to be able to construct the right query that will return all documents where `_id` starts with `http://site/folder`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the better solution is to not use `_id` for this problem.

Instead, index field called `path` (or whatever name you want) and look at using the [Path Hierarchy Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html) with some creative token filters.

This way you can use Elasticsearch/Lucene to tokenize the URLs.

For example: `https://site/folder` gets tokenized as two tokens:

- `site`
- `site/folder`

Then, you could for any file or folder contained in the `site` folder by searching for the right token: `site`.

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "http_dropper": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "^https?:/{0,}(.*)",
          "replacement": "$1"
        },
        "empty_dropper": {
          "type": "length",
          "min": 1
        },
        "qs_dropper": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(.*)[?].*",
          "replacement": "$1"
        },
        "trailing_slash_dropper": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(.*)/+$",
          "replacement": "$1"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "url": {
          "tokenizer": "path_hierarchy",
          "filter": [
            "http_dropper",
            "qs_dropper",
            "trailing_slash_dropper",
            "empty_dropper",
            "unique"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "type" : {
      "properties": {
        "url" : {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "url"
        },
        "type" : {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may *or* may not want the `trailing_slash_dropper` that I added. It may also be worthwhile to have the `lowercase` token filter in there, but that actually could make some URL tokens fundamentally incorrect (e.g., `mysite.com/bucket/AaDsaAe31AcxX` may really care about the case of those characters). You can take the analyzer for a test drive with the `_analyze` endpoint:

```
GET /test/_analyze?analyzer=url&text=http://test.com/text/a/?value=xyz&abc=value
```

Note: I'm using Sense, so it does the URL encoding for me. This will produce three tokens:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "test.com",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "test.com/text",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "test.com/text/a",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Tying it all together:

```
POST /test/type
{
  "type" : "dir",
  "url" : "https://site"
}

POST /test/type
{
  "type" : "dir",
  "url" : "https://site/folder"
}

POST /test/type
{
  "type" : "file",
  "url" : "http://site/folder/document_name.doc"
}

POST /test/type
{
  "type" : "file",
  "url" : "http://other/site/folder/document_name.doc"
}

POST /test/type
{
  "type" : "file",
  "url" : "http://other_site/folder/document_name.doc"
}

POST /test/type
{
  "type" : "file",
  "url" : "http://site/mirror/document_name.doc"
}

GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "url": "http://site/folder"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "file"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It's important to test this so that you can see what matches, and the order of those matches. Naturally this finds the document that you expect it to find (and puts it at the top!), but it also finds some other documents that you might not expect, like `http://site/mirror/document_name.doc` because it shares the base token: `site`. There are a bunch of strategies that you can use to exclude those documents *if* it's important to exclude them.

You can take advantage of your tokenization to perform Google-like results filtering, like how you can search specific domains via Google:

> match query site:elastic.co

You could then parse (manually) the `site:elastic.co` and take the `elastic.co` as a bounding url:

```
{
  "term" : {
    "url" : "elastic.co"
  }
}
```

Note that this is different from searching for the URL. You're explicitly saying "only include documents that contain this *exact* token in their url". You can go further with `site:elastic.co/blog` and so on because that exact token exists. However, it's important to note that if you were to try `site:elastic.co/blog/`, then that would find no documents because that token cannot exist given the token filters.

Comment: Great answer, thank you - I have used it successfully!